# How to down upsample from months to years and also create a multilevel index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

```
I need to convert a table which looks like

ID date_1 date_2 fill_value
1  01-02-2016 04-02-2016  1
1  08-03-2016 01-02-2017  3
2  03-03-2016 04-03-2016  7
```

to

```
ID 01-2016 02-2016 03-2016 04-2016 ... 12-2016
1  1        1       0      0 ...          0
1  0        3       3      3 ...          3
2  0        0       7      0 ...          0
```

and finally to

```
ID 01-2016 02-2016 03-2016 04-2016 ... 12-2016
1  1        4       3      3 ...          3
2  0        0       7      0 ...          0
```

I have tried using the cross tab function and up sample function and then running a for loop. It seems to work but takes more than 3 hours on my machine. Any vectorized solutions?

Comment: can you explain the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try this:

```
df.set_index('ID')\
  .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['fill_value'], 
                             index=pd.date_range(x.date_1, x.date_2, freq='D')),
         axis=1)\
  .sum(level=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what rules do you want to code for transformation from initial table to intermediate one.

For the second transformation try:

`df.groupby('ID').sum()`